# Is there any way to traverse a tree with LINQ/Entity Framework using navigable properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to use Entity Framework's navigable properties inside a LINQ expression to traverse a tree through Parent references. I can't find a good way to go X layers up the tree without having to do X number of joins in the LINQ expression.

My current implementation has a GetAncestors function (on the node) that gets a specific ancestor by referencing the current node's parent until it finds the desired layer. The issue is that LINQ to entities only supports initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties (I.e. calling node.Parent.Parent.Parent works, but doesn't work for a variable tree depth).

Is there any way to get around this in a way that can be extended to other uses?

EDIT: Here's an example of what i'm trying to do/what I have so far

```
public class TestLINQ
{
    public TestLINQ()
    {
        var targetRootId = 1;

        // OLD METHOD - this method assumes that every child3 has a direct reference to a Root ancestor
        // Goal is to remove tree jumping references, and only define parent and child on any given node
        IQueryable<int> child3Ids = (from root in dbContext.Root
                        join child3 in dbContext.Child3 on root.Id equals child3.RootId
                        join child4 in dbContext.Child4 on child3.Id equals child4.ParentId
                        where root.Id == targetRootId && child4.SomeValue == true
                        select child3.Id)
                        .Distinct();

        // NEW METHOD - this method utilizes the GetAncestor function in order to work it's way up the tree
        // This doesn't work because child3.Root.Id will throw an error saying that LINQ to entities only supports initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties. However, it's worth noting that I am able to call child3.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id (3->2->1->Root) and it will work - this isn't reliable because the path to the Root object might be different due to the rules of the tree structure (could be Root->1->1->1->2->2->3)
        IQueryable<int> child3Ids = (from root in dbContext.Root
                                     join child3 in dbContext.Node on root.Id equals child3.Root.Id
                                     join child4 in dbContext.Child4 on child3.Id equals child4.ParentId
                                     where root.Id == targetRootId && child4.SomeValue == true
                                     select child3.Id)
                        .Distinct();
    }
}

// Define generic interface
public interface INode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NodeType type { get; set; }
    public Node node { get; set; }
}

// Implement the interface with a specific object
// This would have a foriegn key relating the id of a Root object with the id of a Node object
public class Root : INode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NodeType type { get => NodeType.Root; }
}

// One for each NodeType (not going to do the rest but you get the idea...)
public class ChildOne : INode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NodeType type { get => NodeType.ChildOne; }
}

// This is our navigation object (used to traverse the tree)
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public NodeType type { get; set; }

    // Define a virtual object that will map to the Root object (this creates a circular reference)
    public virtual Root _root { get; set; }
    public Root Root { get => GetAncestor(NodeType.Root)._root; set => _root = value; }

    // Again, do the same thing for each NodeType
    public virtual ChildOne _ChildOne { get; set; }
    public ChildOne ChildOne { get => GetAncestor(NodeType.Root)._ChildOne; set => _root = value; }

    // ParentId is nullable because Root object can't have parents
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public Node GetAncestor(NodeType targetType)
    {
        if (targetType > this.type)
        {
            return null; // Ancestor must be above the current node in the tree
        }

        if (type != targetType)
        {
            return Parent?.GetAncestor(targetType);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

// Tree structure is setup s.t. 
// Roots cannot have a parent
// Roots can only have children of type ChildOne
// Any given child type can have both children of same type and one level lower
//          E.g. ChildOne can have both ChildOne children AND ChildTwo children
public enum NodeType
{
    Root,
    ChildOne,
    ChildTwo,
    ChildThree,
    ChildFour,
    ChildFive
}
```

Comment: How would you accomplish this outside of EF? Do you have some sample code that you would like to translate into an EF store expression?

Comment: You could potentially create an accessor function that builds the access to a desired depth, but you would probably need to propagate the `Expression` tree build up to the highest or second highest layer (i.e. you couldn't use it inside a lambda, but to replace a lambda). Can you show how you would use this?

Comment: What is `child3.Root`? Can you use cross-join instead of `join` e.g. `from child3 in dbContext.Node where root.Id == child3.Root.Id` ?

Comment: Calling .Root on any Node object refers to the custom getter method that will retrieve the Root object using the GetAncestor method (either from the current Node or somewhere up the Node tree)